# R shift of the plots

Tags: r, plot

I have a code in R

```
x=rnorm(1000,1,1)
quantile(x,0.05)


x1=rnorm(1000,-10,1)

sum(x1>quantile(x,0.05))/length(x1)

y=hist(x,plot=FALSE)$density

plot(y)

plot(y,type="l")


y1=hist(x1,plot=FALSE)$density
matplot(y1,type="l",add=TRUE)
```

I want to change it so that the plots do not overlap but are next to each other. Is it enough that I change the values for the mean and sd or I have to change something else in the code. I am new to this, so please help me

Comment: If you want the two plots side by side, then something like this should work `layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1)); plot(y,type="l"); matplot(y1,type="l")`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I mean I want them spaced apart but on the same x-axis

Comment: I want them to be pushed aside as histograms in the picture in the question of another user https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346963/r-using-matplot

Comment: Is that also your question? Have you created multiple Stack Overflow accounts? You should not post the same question multiple times. Also note that help might not come immediately. You should be patient. Do you want the x-axis to have any meaning? If the data shares a common mean, what's to decide how far apart they should be on the x-axis in your desired plot?

Comment: Yes that's my question, I only have one email and one account.

Comment: Data have a different means 1 and -10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot both histograms, you need to set the correct x and y limits for the plot windows because base R graphics will not resize the window after the first set of data has been drawn. Here's one way to do that

```
x <- rnorm(1000,1,1)
x1 <- rnorm(1000,-10,1)

y <- hist(x,plot=FALSE)
y1 <- hist(x1, plot=FALSE)

plot(0,0, 
  ylim=range(c(y$counts, y1$counts)), 
  xlim=range(c(y$breaks, y1$breaks)), 
  xlab="x", ylab="counts", type="n")
plot(y, add=TRUE)
plot(y1, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you,  MrFlick it helped me a lot, and one more last question, if I want, that the mean was visible for each of the histograms in the form of an orange bar?